# ubuntu document repository

Tags: pdf, source

i am looking for document repository system that i can host in my ubuntu server and be accessed by clients locally. These are the features of concern:
- associate documents with names, id no, registration year
- be able to sort using names, or registration year
- be able to search

NB: several documents belong to one person. and there about 200 persons docs to manage.
what ubuntu open source software can help here?

Comment: i would hope to be private repository, and searches should disp

Comment: something like this? https://www.openkm.com/blog/openkm-and-ubuntu-the-perfect-combination-open-source.html  it is a webbased DMS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your are looking for an -open source- [**D**ocument **M**anagement **S**ystem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_management_system#Components)
It is is a system used to track, manage and store documents
It includes users management, versioning, metadata indexing, searching ...

Several Open Source DMS are heavy systems (ie complicated features & uses) offering more than DMS.

The big question is which one for your needs. I'll go with [SeedDMS](http://www.seeddms.org) as its up-to-date and simple compared to others.

Find more information :
 - https://opensource-it.com/open-source-dms/
 - https://www.efilecabinet.com/open-source-document-management-systems-comparison-efilecabinet/
 - https://www.how2shout.com/tools/best-free-open-source-document-management-system-software.html